# Nexmo not sending sms in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, vonage

I'm using nexmo sms api to send messages to mobile numbers. It is working fine,I  get the results also but sms is not sent to the mobile number.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Nexmo = require('nexmo');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const nexmo = new Nexmo({
  apiKey: 'db8*****',
  apiSecret: 'kimQ************',
}, {debug: true});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  nexmo.message.sendSms('NEXMO', req.body.toNumber, req.body.message, {type: 'unicode'}, (err, responseData) => {
      if (responseData){
          console.log(responseData);
          res.send(responseData);
      }
  });
});
```

I'm using postman to send post request.
I get normal results as **responseData** but sms not sent to number.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: What is `err` returned as?

Comment: I get fine results, no any error.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(req.body);`

Comment: { toNumber: '9193********', message: 'hello deepu' } ...exectly the body that i send.

Comment: And does the Nexmo dashboard give any indication as to what is going on? You also have `debug` set to true. Is that giving any information?

Comment: problem is same when it is set to false

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. My question was does that give any indication as to what is going on? Not if the problem exists if it's false. Honestly the problem here is you didn't follow the Stack Overflow guidelines in the [help]. Please read [mcve]. This is not a problem that is easily reproducible. The only major thing that looks wrong with your code itself is that I'm not 100% sure that you can pass in a string like that as the sender.

Comment: I got messages to my number after 10 hours.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use "NEXMO" as the from number and some networks require you to have a valid phone number or alphanumeric short code in order for messages to be delivered. You can check [here](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011781468) under the "Alpha SenderID Support" column for the country you're trying to message to see if this is supported. For now, try changing "NEXMO" to a Nexmo number under your account:

```
nexmo.message.sendSms('YOUR_NEXMO_NUMBER_HERE', req.body.toNumber, req.body.message, {type: 'unicode'}, (err, responseData) => {
  if (responseData){
      console.log(responseData);
      res.send(responseData);
  }
});
```